# Communication between 2 independent components angularJS 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 independent components inside app component. The first one is toolbar and the other one is sidenav component. What I would like to achieve and I have done it(using reactive x pattern) is when a button is clicked from toolbar, sidenav toggles between 2 states(from 64px to 240px width and vice versa).

I have used a generic Behaviour subject inside a shared service to emit data from when toolbar button is clicked and a subscriber inside sidenav component to listen to the emitted data.

My question is if there is a way to accomplish the same result using another approach(like @Input or @Output as stated in official docs) or reactive x pattern feeds perfect in my needs?

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    FirmsComponent,
    SidenavComponent, //sidenav component being injected
    ToolbarComponent // toolbar component being injected
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    FlexLayoutModule.forRoot()
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]

 })
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxFill>
    <toolbar></toolbar>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxFill>
        <sidenav></sidenav>
        <div fxFlex>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

toolbar.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'toolbar',
templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
})

export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
 showNavBar: boolean = false;

 constructor(private globalEventsManager: GlobalEventsManager) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeToolbar();
 }

 ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // this.globalEventsManager.globalEventsEmitter().unsubscribe();
 }

 initializeToolbar() {
    this.globalEventsManager.globalEventsEmitter()
        .filter(params => params.action === 'handleItemVbl')
        .subscribe(params => {
            (params !== null) && (this.showNavBar = params.show);
    });
 }
 //emit data when button is clicked
 toggleSidenav() {
    this.globalEventsManager.emitEvent({ action: 'toggleSidenav' });
 }
}
```

sidenav.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'sidenav',
templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
})
export class SidenavComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
 showNavBar: boolean = false;
 isHovered: boolean = false;
 toggled: boolean = false;

 constructor(private globalEventsManager: GlobalEventsManager) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeSidenav();
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
    // this.globalEventsManager.globalEventsEmitter().unsubscribe();
 }

 initializeSidenav() {
    this.globalEventsManager.globalEventsEmitter()
            .filter(params => params.action === 'handleItemVbl')
            .subscribe(params => {
                (params !== null) && (this.showNavBar = params.show);

    });
    //sidenav component is listening for data emittions  
    this.globalEventsManager.globalEventsEmitter()
        .filter(params => params.action === 'toggleSidenav')
        .subscribe(params => {
            if (params !== null) !this.toggled ? this.toggled = true :  this.toggled = false;
    });
 }

 onHover() {
    this.isHovered = true;
 }

 onLeave() {
    // !this.exp && (this.isHovered = false);
    this.isHovered = false
 }
}
```

sharedservice.ts

```
export class GlobalEventsManager {

private _globalBehaviorSubj: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

constructor() {}

 emitEvent(params) {
    this._globalBehaviorSubj.next(params);
 }

 globalEventsEmitter(): Observable<any> {
    return this._globalBehaviorSubj.asObservable();
 }
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as angularJS 2. Angular and AngularJS are different frameworks, A2 questions shouldn't have angularjs tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `AppComponent` should contain sidenav state and pass it down to `SidenavComponent`. `ToolbarComponent` should emit event when button is clicked so `AppComponent` can change sidenav's state.